# Proving continuity in case of unifrom convergence

Tags: calculus

I got stuck a little bit and I could use some help. Thanks in advance for your time!

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions and $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$.
>   Prove that f is also a continuous function.

Comment: Is "string" a bad translation of "sequence" or a valid synonym?

Comment: My bad, it's a sequence

Comment: @angryavian and other voters to close (as duplicate): what the heck? Uniform convergence and uniform continuity are completely different things.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, my mistake... I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the continuity of $f$ you have to bound $f(y)-f(x)$ (for normed spaces, $d(f(y),f(x))$ for metric ones). To do that, consider one function of the sequence $f_n$ and go over the other three sides of the rectangle with corners $\{n,\infty\}×\{x,y\}$, i.e., the path of values
$$f(x)\to f_n(x)\to f_n(y) \to f(y).$$ Now you arrange that, for example, each of the distances are less than $\varepsilon/3$ by selecting a lower bound $N$ for $n$ and a radius $\delta$ for $y\in B(x,δ)$. Then you get in the sum of the distances and via triangle inequality $|f(y)-f(x)|<ε$.